# MySQL 5.1 / MariaDB 5.5 temporary table behavior change

Tags: mysql, mariadb

While testing the upgrade from MySQL 5.1 to MariaDB 5.5 I ran into the following change in behavior.

Please note this is using a non-root user with alter table privileges on a slave (read-only) server in both cases.

**MySQl 5.1:**

```
mysql> create temporary table testtest (id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE `testtest` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**MariaDB 5.5:**

```
MariaDB [pollstream_common]> create temporary table testtest (id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

MariaDB [pollstream_common]> ALTER TABLE `testtest` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`);
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MariaDB server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Does anyone know if this change in behavior is by design or, either way, if there may be a workaround for it? Since it would be a considerable undertaking to change and test existent code which was implemented using the former version and which has been working for a while.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you've run into [this bug](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-6581). As a workaround, disable the read_only via `SET GLOBAL read_only = 0` or changing it in the `my.cnf` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was quite tricky. What we found out is that it *only* comes up if the engine is innodb (!), which is the default type for MariaDB (or at least it is in Centos 7).

Once we set default-storage-engine=myisam in my.cnf the problem went away. I suspect it's a bug and not the intended behavior, but this is how it's fixed.

Comment: 5.7 is revamping the handling of temp tables in InnoDB.  We may have to wait for that version for the 'real' fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
create temporary table testtest (id int, PRIMARY KEY(`id`));
```

avoids the problem.

Why was it read_only?  Perhaps it is a Slave?  Or a Master in a dual-master, single-writer setup?  I would not turn off `read_only` without understanding why it was on -- it is not on by default.

The underlying [MySQL bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62008) (which probably leads to the MariaDB bug) suggests that `binlog_format = ROW` may be a solution.

Comment: Yes, it was read_only because it was a slave. We found out the underlying issue was with the engine type, since once we switched the default to myisam (which meant temporary tables were created using that type) it worked.

Comment: Hmmm...  I would call it a bug not to be able to manipulate a temp table on a read_only server.